# What is the physical meaning of the Fourier transform of the creation/annhilation operators in the nearest neighbour model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, lattice-model, normal-modes

It is possible to take the Fourier transform of the creation operator as

$$a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_n e^{-ik\cdot n}a_n$$

with $k=2\pi l/N$ and $l=\{-N/2+1, -N/2 +2  ... N/2\}$

but I am really struggling to get my head around what this could actually represent.

Say for example we have a lattice of N=4 then our operator would become:

$$a_k=\frac{1}{2}(ia_1-a_2-ia_3+a_4)$$

what does this mean?

Comment: Clearest interpretation is just creation/ annihilation of different modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates/annihilates a particle that is not in a position eigenstate but instead a momentum eigenstate $p = k\hbar$ - i.e. its wavefunction is a plane wave with a single wave vector $k$.